# Does a react hook add an event listener every time it's called?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks, addeventlistener

Let's say I have a react hook that listens to an event like `resize` on the `window` object.

I want to know if every time I use the hook in some components all over the application I'm also adding a different event listener on `window`.

If the answer is yes, then i suppose this will be bad for performances, how can i avoid it?

Here's an example of the hook i want to implement:

```
export const useMediaQuery = (): ReturnObject => {
  const [desktop, setDesktop] = useState(false);
  const getViewport = (): void => {
    setDesktop(window.matchMedia(desktopQuery).matches);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getViewport();
    const listener = (): void => getViewport();
    window.addEventListener('resize', listener);
    return (): void => window.removeEventListener('resize', listener);
  }, []);

  return {
    deviceType: desktop ? DeviceType.Desktop : DeviceType.Mobile,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use **custom hooks**, React will allocate a new piece of memory for that component to use that custom hook.

so, I think the answer is **YES**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).